# How to conditionally validate an array input in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to conditionally validate an array input in Laravel. I am following the documentation provided [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules). But the documentation does not provide details on how to do it on an array input. Below is the code that I am trying

```
$rule = [
            'report.*' => 'max:255',
            'comment.*' => 'exclude_if:report.*,file|max:65535'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($array, $rule);
```

Here the report is a file input and comment is a text area field.

```
<input type="file" name="report[0]"/>
<input type="file" name="report[1]"/>
<textarea name="comment[0]"></textarea>
<textarea name="comment[1]"></textarea>
```

The comment field is required if the corresponding file input is empty. How can I achieve this in Laravel 7?

Comment: I think you should use a custom rule here, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but maybe change the structure to something like `report[0][file]` and `report[0][comment]`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try required_if ?

And i think you must write "report" instead of "file" because your input name is report.

If that doesn't work, maybe you need to make a custom rule.

Comment: Close enough! I used 'required_without' and it worked. 'required_if' is to check if the other field is present. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using below code.

```
$rule = [
            'report.*' => 'max:255',
            'comment.*' => 'required_without:report.*|max:65535'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($array, $rule);
```